# Monero Testnet Faucet

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, testnet

How to run monero node in testnet mode for testing purpose and how to get testnet coin? Is there any testnet online portal for testing?

Answer (score 3):

1. Start the daemon: `monerod --testnet` and then once sync'ed...
2. Start the wallet in another window: `monero-wallet-cli --testnet` to create a testnet wallet, then...
3. Back in the running daemon type: `start_mining <your-wallet-address-here>`
4. Wait to mine a block. You'll then have testnet coins.

Answer (score 2):

There's a testnet and stagenet faucet currently provided by xmr.to: https://community.xmr.to/faucet/testnet/

Answer (score 0):

There's a testnet and stagenet faucet currently provided by rino.io

https://community.rino.io/faucet/stagenet/